# Почему ошибка и как это исправить?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот

```
PS C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\telegram_bot> python -m venv venv
PS C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\telegram_bot> venv\Scripts\activate
venv\Scripts\activate : Невозможно загрузить файл C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\telegram_bot\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1, так ка
к выполнение сценариев отключено в этой системе. Для получения дополнительных сведений см. about_Execution_Policies по
адресу https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
строка:1 знак:1
+ venv\Scripts\activate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : Ошибка безопасности: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

[image: описание]

Answer (score 0):

самое простое решение это запустить скрипт через [cmd](https://www.google.com/search?q=cmd&oq=cmd&aqs=chrome..69i57.825j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) или какие либо [IDE](https://www.google.com/search?q=IDE&sxsrf=ALiCzsZL87KrGW5RHzBAo6v64fxUXzeANQ%3A1662299217580&ei=UawUY8CHI8_KrgSwvb0o&ved=0ahUKEwiA9P6So_v5AhVPpYsKHbBeDwUQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=IDE&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgjECcyDgguEIAEELEDEMcBENEDMhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARDRAzIICAAQgAQQsQMyEQguEIAEELEDEIMBEMcBENEDMgsIABCABBCxAxCDATIFCAAQgAQyCAgAEIAEELEDMgsIABCABBCxAxCDATIICC4QgAQQsQM6CggAEEcQ1gQQsAM6BwgjEOoCECc6CwguEIAEEMcBEK8BOgQIABBDOgoIABCxAxCDARBDOgcIABCxAxBDSgQIQRgASgQIRhgAUIMFWPoOYPARaANwAXgAgAGGAYgBywOSAQMxLjOYAQCgAQGwAQrIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz) например VSCode или Pycharm,
либо можно решить проблему и запускать все через powershell таким образом:

Шаг1: Открываем powershell от имени администратора.

Шаг2: Пишем: Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

Шаг3: Везде отвечаем (A)

А так же научитесь читать ошибки, наверное это очень сложно вить читать не умеют аж целых [750млн](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%8E%D1%82%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&sxsrf=ALiCzsZXk2rKi2p90WgG6a0LolbTlMjWWg%3A1662299258915&ei=eqwUY9LDN6ubwPAPiOWn-Ag&ved=0ahUKEwjS6Nmmo_v5AhWrDRAIHYjyCY8Q4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%8E%D1%82%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIGCAAQHhAWMgYIABAeEBY6BwgjELADECc6CggAEEcQ1gQQsAM6BwgAELADEEM6DQgAEOQCENYEELADGAE6EgguEMcBENEDEMgDELADEEMYAjoHCCMQ6gIQJzoECCMQJzoLCAAQgAQQsQMQgwE6CAguELEDEIMBOgQIABBDOggIABCxAxCDAToKCAAQsQMQgwEQQzoICAAQgAQQsQM6DgguEIAEELEDEIMBENQCOgsILhCABBCxAxCDAToICC4QgAQQsQM6CAgAEIAEEMkDSgQIQRgASgQIRhgBUJwFWOomYP0oaAJwAXgAgAHNAYgB8xmSAQY5LjE5LjGYAQCgAQGwAQrIARHAAQHaAQYIARABGAnaAQYIAhABGAg&sclient=gws-wiz) человек но постарайтесь их читать и главное научитесь понимать их, тогда все проблемы решаться сами

Comment: то есть, если  я пишу в vscode ,то что я делаю в PowerShell не нужно ?это лишнее правильно ?

Comment: да, VsCode сам умеет запускать .ру файлы с использованием самого интерпретатора питона

Answer (score 0):

1. Запустите PowerShell от Администратора
2. Напишите Команду в терминале Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser
   жмите Enter
3. Напишите Y,  жмите Enter, и Вы получите нужные Вам права.